# Saving plots in R as GIFs

Tags: image, r, plot, gif

In R, I use function `savePlot` to save graphs into image files. But my colleague can only open .jpgs and .gifs (probably because he's on vacation, reading emails on his mobile phone). I hate to create jpegs because especially the boxplots looks very ugly (whiskers blurred etc.). But the `savePlot` function only supports the following types:

```
type = c("wmf", "emf", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp",
                  "tif", "tiff", "ps", "eps", "pdf")
```

#### How can I save plot in GIF in R?

EDIT: if possible, ideal solution should work without installing ImageMagick (so that the R script is easily portable).

Comment: Packages `animation` and `caTools` have functions to save gifs: see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/animation.pdf and http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/caTools/html/GIF.html. See also here: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/02/12809.html

Comment: if you can install ImageMagick http://www.imagemagick.org you can save as PNG and `convert myPlot.png myPlot.gif` from the command line, or `system("convert myPlot.png myPlot.gif")` from within R

Comment: Are you sure your colleague can only read GIFs, and not PNGs?  Maybe you could try saving as PNG and sending them a test example ...

Comment: Yes @Ben, I am sure - he complained after I've sent him PNGs :) And thanks, your comment is probably an answer.. the only thing to tune is that the png should be saved as a temp file and removed afterwards.

Answer (score 14):

R doesn't have a native GIF graphics driver, mostly (completely?) due to the patent-encumbrances of the GIF format: see http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/02/12809.html  .

There is a function in the `caTools` package (`write.gif()`) but it is specifically designed for writing images. If you wanted to use it you have to do something hacky to convert your plot to an image first (e.g. save as PNG and then read it back into R as an image).  For example:

```
png("myPlot.png")
plot(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
library(png)
P1 <- readPNG("myPlot.png")
library(caTools)
write.gif(P1,"myPlot.gif")
showGIF <- function(fn) system(paste("display",fn))
showGIF("myPlot.gif")
unlink("myPlot.gif")  ## clean up
```

`?write.gif()` has a lot of stuff about color indexing that I didn't read but that might be important for more complex graphs ...

The `animation` package has a `saveGIF()` function to save GIFs, but (1) it is designed for saving multi-frame animations (not general graphics), and (2) it does it by calling ImageMagick.

It's easier just to construct that function yourself.

- install ImageMagick (http://imagemagick.org)
- save as a PNG, then use ImageMagick to convert.

For example:

```
png("myPlot.png")
plot(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
system("convert myPlot.png myPlot.gif")
unlink("myPlot.png") ## clean up
showGIF("myPlot.gif")
unlink("myPlot.gif") ## clean up
```

Of course you can either of these in a function if you want to use them regularly.

**UPDATE**: I spent a while longer on this, to try to get a pure-R solution, but don't yet have a working solution.  Suggestions or edits welcome ...

```
## needs ImageMagick: just for testing ...
showGIF <- function(fn) system(paste("display",fn))
```

The main function:

```
saveGIF <- function(fn,verbose=FALSE,debug=FALSE) {
    require(png)
    require(caTools)
    tmpfn <- tempfile()
    on.exit(unlink(tmpfn))
    savePlot(tmpfn,type="png")
    P1 <- readPNG(tmpfn)
    dd <- dim(P1)
    P1 <- aperm(P1,c(3,1,2),resize=TRUE)  ## P1[,1,15]
    dim(P1) <- c(dd[3],prod(dd[1:2]))
    P1 <- t(P1)
    if (verbose) cat("finding unique colours ...\n")
    P1u <- unique(P1)
    rgbMat <- function(x) {
        rgb(x[,1],x[,2],x[,3])
    }
    if (verbose) cat("creating colour index ...\n")
    pp <- paste(P1[,1],P1[,2],P1[,3],sep=".")
    ## make sure factor is correctly ordered
    ind <- as.numeric(factor(pp,levels=unique(pp))) 
    if (verbose) cat("finding colour palette ...\n")
    if (nrow(P1u)>256) {
        if (verbose) cat("kmeans clustering ...\n")
        kk <- kmeans(P1u,centers=256)
        ind <- kk$cluster[ind]
        pal <- rgbMat(kk$centers)
    } else {
        pal <- rgbMat(P1u)
    }
    ## test:
    if (debug) {
        dev.new()
        par(mar=rep(0,4))
        image(t(matrix(ind-1,nrow=dd[1])),col=pal,axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
    }
    if (verbose) cat("writing GIF ...\n")
    indmat <- matrix(ind-1,nrow=dd[1])
    storage.mode(indmat) <- "integer"
    write.gif(indmat,fn,col=as.list(pal),scale="never")
}


X11.options(antialias="none")
image(matrix(1:64,nrow=8),col=rainbow(10))
saveGIF("tmp.gif",verbose=TRUE,debug=TRUE)
showGIF("tmp.gif")
```

Comment: Thank you Ben! I would like a solution that would work without installing ImageMagick (so that the R script is easily portable), but the first solution with `write.gif` does not work. It produces animated greyscale (!) gif. Seems that the `write.gif` function is not able to produce optimal palette (i.e. doesn't have the color clustering algorithm to create optimal 256 colour palette).

Comment: it looks like `write.gif` may have some more options -- did you try `scale="never"`?  It certainly doesn't seem to have colour clustering algorithm, but a relatively simple graphic might not need one ...